# Temporary value is freed at the end of this statement

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using the Select crate:

```
let document = Document::from_read(response).unwrap();

for node in document.find(Class("lia-list-row")) {
    let title = node.find(Class("page-link")).next().unwrap();
    let title_text = title.text().trim();

    println!("{}\n", title_text);
}
```

Which results in following error:

```
let title_text = title.text().trim();
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^       - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
                 |
                 creates a temporary which is freed while still in use

println!("{} - {}\n", i, title_text);
                         ---------- borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
```

I solved it by separating the `.text()` and `.trim()`

```
let title_text = title.text();
let trim_text = title_text.trim();
```

What is the difference? Why did the first attempt fail?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This one seems convoluted at first, but remember that `String` and `&str` are different beasts.

`String` can live and be used on its own, but `&str` is just a reference to part of `String`. So, `&str` can live as long as referenced `String` lives. Lets see how it should work on return signatures.

```
let title_text = title   .text()   .trim();
//               ^       ^         ^
//               Node    String <- &str
```

1. Here, `title` is a [`select::Node`](https://docs.rs/select/0.4.2/select/node/struct.Node.html).
2. [`Node::text`](https://docs.rs/select/0.4.2/select/node/struct.Node.html#method.text) returns a `String`, but nothing binds it to context.
3. [`String::trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim), in turn, returns a `&str` which is a reference to part of `String` itself.

In the end, the borrow checker just doesn't understand how it should process a reference to `String` that will not live long enough in context, as it is a temporary value (non-bound).

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without declaring a new variable?

Comment: @rm.rf.etc you could use `title.text().trim().to_string()` if you tolerate a copy.

Comment: Is `let text = &title.text().trim().to_owned()` what we want here typically to avoid copy and just extend lifetime of reference?