# How do I fix "creates a temporary which is freed while still in use" without creating additional variable?

Tags: rust

I've encountered a simple task: I want to pass a sum of strings to a constructor of an object. In my case, I wanted to create a `Path` from a sum of `&str`, like this:

```
const BASE_PATH: &str = "/some/path/";

fn main() {
    let write_br_path = Path::new(BASE_PATH + "brightness");
}
```

However, I soon found out that I can't sum &str and &str, so, as my compiler suggested, I did something like this:

```
let write_br_path = Path::new(&(BASE_PATH.to_owned() + "brightness"));
```

However, this also didn't work. This code failed to compile, informing me that "creates a temporary which is freed while still in use". I've come up with a simple solution:

```
let m_b = BASE_PATH.to_owned() + "max_brightness";
let max_br_path = Path::new(&(m_b));
```

This leaves me with a question: can this code be written in a more compact way, without additional variable being created?

Comment: Use `PathBuf` instead?

Comment: @justinas well, such a problem can occur with pretty much anything, not only paths. I'm looking for a more general solution. However, looks like `PathBuf` solves this case, thanks!

Comment: I would advise reading answers to similar problems, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056268/temporary-value-is-freed-at-the-end-of-this-statement), or more resources on what references/borrows are in Rust. `Path` and `PathBuf` have a smilar relationship as `str` and `String` have.

Comment: @biryulin04 the general solution would be to make an additional variable because you can't make a temporary object live longer than the current statement without it.

Comment: `Path::new()` is peculiar and may not be a good example on the usefulness of the various idioms for string catenation. You can see the answer I posted for details on why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I fix “creates a temporary which is freed while still in use” without creating additional variable?

You can refactor your code into a `match` where the variable is bound via an arm:

```
match Path::new(&(BASE_PATH.to_owned() + "brightness")) {
    write_br_path => {
        println!("{:?}", write_br_path);
    }
};
```

Since it is part of the match expression, the temporary created by `BASE_PATH.to_owned() + "brightness"` is not dropped until the end of it, meaning you can continue to use `write_br_path` within the arm without a problem.

*I do not actually suggest doing this*.

You need an additional variable because of the rules for [temporary scopes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes).

This is probably not as compact as you'd like, but a fairly common thing to do is to make an additional variable and [*shadow*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html#shadowing) it:

```
let max_br_path = BASE_PATH.to_owned() + "max_brightness";
let max_br_path = Path::new(&max_br_path);
```

This can be nice to avoid misusing the original variable and enforce use of its shadow. This is mentioned in the rust [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#comparing-the-guess-to-the-secret-number) in the guessing game tutorial: *"This feature is often used in situations in which you want to convert a value from one type to another type."*

Comment: But why does shadowing help here? If I get it correctly, `Path::new` doesn't copy the string passed - it just saves the reference. Doesn't that mean that when `max_br_path` is shadowed and the string it was storing gets freed the reference saved in `Path` object points to nothing? I'm new to Rust, so I have some problems understanding the memory model.

Comment: Shadowing doesn't necessarily help much, just keeps you from having multiple (potentially confusing) variable names polluting the function. *"is shadowed and the string it was storing gets freed"* - shadowing a variable doesn't destroy it, it will be dropped at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question as it relates to `Path::new()` specifically, you invoke `Path::new()` where you need it without assigning it to a variable.

For instance, to pass a `Path` reference to another function, or macro, such as `println!()`, invoke `Path::new()` in the parameter list:

```rust
println!("{:?}", Path::new(&[BASE_PATH, "brightness"].concat()));
```

^^ this works because neither `Path::new()`, nor `.concat()`'s return value is being bound to a variable. They're both used once in place.

Although the same code worked when passed to `println!()` in the example above, the same code in the following example doesn't work because the return value of `Path::new()` has a `let` binding, but the actual data it depends on doesn't:

```rust
let p = Path::new(&[BASE_PATH, "brightness"].concat()); // Error...
```

The reason for the need to assign to a new variable is peculiar to `Path::new()` since it's a 0-cost conversion operation. It doesn't otherwise do anything with the value passed to it, and it returns a reference rather than a concrete object.

From [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.new) on `Path::new()`:

```rust
pub fn new<S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(s: &S) -> &Path
```

> Directly wraps a string slice as a Path slice.
> This is a cost-free conversion.

If you're going to bind the return value of `Path::new()` to a variable, the actual data it depends on needs to be a static string or a string also bound to a variable.

There are a lot of ways to combine strings. [This page](https://github.com/hoodie/concatenation_benchmarks-rs) gives a number of options and has benchmark figures on the performance of each.